# How to associate an action to a keyboard shortcut?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, keyboard, nsdocument, nsmenu

I've an IBAction that calls up a panel. I want to invoke that action with a keyboard shortcut but I'm at a loss on how to do it.

I guess one way of doing it would be to create a menu item, associate the action to the item and then assign the shortcut to that item, but I haven't done my menus yet.

Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: Being of the short memory type I asked the question a second time: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1876086/hotkeys-key-events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I guess one way of doing it would be
>   to create a menu item, associate the
>   action to the item and then assign the
>   shortcut to that item, but I haven't
>   done my menus yet.

I think you anwered the question yourself :)
Just create a UI Element in Interface Builder that's supposed to start your Action and assign an [Key Equivalent](http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/IB_UserGuide/ObjectAttributes/ObjectAttributes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005344-CH20-SW5).

Comment: I guess I should get going with those menus :)